# Deploying Django application with Heroku and getting AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm triying to deploy my app to Heroku, Iget this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

my **DATABASE** setting in the `settings.py`:

```py
import dj_database_url
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS")
DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False") == "True"
...
if DEVELOPMENT_MODE is True:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis",
            "NAME": "manage",
            "USER": "testuser",
            "PASSWORD": "Lin123",
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": "",
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0:
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.config(),
    }
...
import django_heroku

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv("GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH")
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv("GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH")

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

It's my first deploy of an app and I'm not sur about what I'm doing wrong.
When I try to access the webpage I get this from logs tail:

```
10.1.36.236 - - [27/Sep/2021:18:06:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"
2021-09-27T18:06:17.924262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stjg.herokuapp.com request_id=5f97c187-c91a-4bec-861b-97ffec6d00e9 fwd="196.75.250.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=184ms status=500 bytes=403 protocol=https
2021-09-27T18:07:07.197074+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user ezzi.mohammed1@yahoo.fr
2021-09-27T18:07:13.279256+00:00 heroku[run.3281]: Awaiting client
2021-09-27T18:07:13.303360+00:00 heroku[run.3281]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-09-27T18:07:13.428317+00:00 heroku[run.3281]: State changed from starting to up
2021-09-27T18:07:18.256114+00:00 heroku[run.3281]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-27T18:07:18.310315+00:00 heroku[run.3281]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: Have you `DEVELOPMENT_MODE  is True` when you deploye on heroku ? Ensure you that `"ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"` is set even if  the  `DEVELOPMENT_MODE`  is `False`

Comment: yes, I have this error when I try `heroku run python manage.py migrate` in the web link to my app I get *error 500*

Comment: @Rvector do I need to change the DATABASE setting ?

Comment: I don't know if `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` is supported by heroku !  But try to add `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`  when DEBUG is `False` too.

Comment: @Rvector I tried without `DEVELOPMENT_MODE` condition and set the `DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config(),}`  but still get the same error.